# Weird characters inside my XML file when sending SMTP mail

Tags: c#, xml, email, smtp, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a XML file via e-mail, but when I receive the mail in my inbox "3D" pops up in my xml declaration.

This is what my XML file looks like when I serialize it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PositionOpeningNL xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></<PositionOpeningNL>
```

and this is how it shows up in my mail

```
From: db6faa544039df <********-ef6b15@inbox.mailtrap.io>
Date: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 10:01:20 +0100
Subject: XML
Message-Id: <****************@DESKTOP-*********>
To: Mo <e-mail>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; name=debug.xml
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=debug.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<?xml version=3D"1.0"?>
<PositionOpeningNL xmlns:xsi=3D"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-insta=
nce" xmlns:xsd=3D"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  </PositionOpeningNL>
```

I'm using mailtrap as a mail server. I don't know if it's something the service adds to my XML file or if it's something I need to change in my code.

Here's how I serialize the XML file and send it. I'm using MailKit : https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;
public class PositionOpeningNL
{

}

 var convert = new PositionOpeningNL();
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(convert.GetType());

            //serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, convert);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "//debug.xml",
                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(fs, convert);
                //MessageBox.Show("Created");
            }

            var message = new MimeMessage();
            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("db6faa544039df", "******-ef6b15@inbox.mailtrap.io"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Mo", "e-mail"));
            message.Subject = "XML";
            builder.Attachments.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "//debug.xml");
            message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
            //message.Attachments = ser;
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {

                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, f) => true;

                client.Connect("smtp.mailtrap.io", 465, false);
                client.Authenticate("username", "password");
                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);

            }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: You already have the xml file in the correct format? If so there is no need the serialize it again. Attach the xml file to the email without serializing it again.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, but thanks anyway for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the service I was using. I replaced mailtrap with office365 and the characters don't show up anymore. I also noticed that  there was nothing wrong with the attachment in either services. It's likely that the raw output of the mail made it look like there where characters in the file itself.